# When is the integral group ring Noetherian?

Tags: group-algebras

The integral group ring of a polycyclic-by-finite group was shown to be Noetherian by Philip Hall. Are there any other known examples?

Comment: This very question was addressed here https://mathoverflow.net/a/165065/14094 in this generality (although the question was more of a particular case).

Answer (score 10):

As far as I know the only groups known to have a Noetherian integral group ring are polycyclic-by-finite groups. This is often discussed in connection with the so-called "Zero Divisor Conjecture" for amenable groups of finite cohomological dimension, whose integral group ring is noetherian, e.g., see [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.5813) (in particular, page $5$).